# Delete array from mysql

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have a array(string).
$url array is contain lot of url

```
foreach ($array as $url){
$sql = "DELETE FROM url WHERE url='".$url."'";
if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) { echo "Its Delete";}
}
```

Its just show echo text, dosent delete from db.
i tried lot of way but still dosent work.
Can u help me?

Comment: You're just checking if the query was successful, not how many rows were affected. See [`$conn->affected_rows;`](http://php.net/mysqli.affected-rows)

Comment: i did it but it say 0

Comment: There was no match. Check the urls.

Comment: Right, so as suspected, if `$conn->affected_rows` returned zero, then there were no matches in the table matching the `url` column to the `$url` value. Check your database and the contents of `$url` and piece it together.

Comment: Maybe if you look at what is in `$array` with a `print_r($array);` and compare it with your database

Comment: ohh guys thank y i didnt notice empty place at end of string i waste 4 hour my life

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You are doing correct but it is not recommended to hit **database** in a **loop**
 so do like this

```
if(!empty($array)){
    $url = '("' . implode('","', $array) . '")';
    $sql = "DELETE FROM url WHERE url in " . $url . "";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);
    if ($result) {
        echo "Its Delete";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that you're getting the correct rows from your query. You can do something like this:

```
foreach ($array as $url) {
    $sql = "DELETE FROM url WHERE url='".$url."'";
    echo $sql.PHP_EOL;
}
```

Run the echo'd queries directly to mysql, that way, you'll understand why it's failing.

Also, make sure you're using the correct table: `url`